# C++ primer 5th edition switch statement

Tags: c++, scope, switch-statement, declaration

In C++ primer 5th edition the solutions appendix, gives an example about `switch` statement:

> ```
>  case true:
>      string file_name; // error: control bypasses an implicitly initialized variable.
>      ...
>  case false:
>      if(file_name.empty()); // file_name is in scope but wasn't initialized.
> ```

But I think it is wrong because `file_name` has been implicitly initialized and that is why the compiler flags that error.

```
struct Foo{};
switch(val){
    case 1:
       Foo f; // ok not-implicitly initialized like std::string
    break;
    case 2:
        f.some_member(); // use f;
}
```

So are my guesses correct?

Comment: What is "implicitly initialized"?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: `file_name` which is of type `std::string`. Without explicitly value-init like `Foo f{};` I think. That expression "implicitly initialized " is in the book.

Comment: That doesn't explain it. `file_name` has a type, so?

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. When you write "I think it is wrong": what is wrong? As for asking questions about code snippets there are no guesses needed: compile the code, see what happens. Godbolt.org is free. Use it!

Comment: If "implicitly initialized" is in the book, it either failed to define it properly, or there is some misunderstanding here. That's a meaningless term outside that realm. Perhaps what's meant here is "default initialized"?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: The error generated by the compiler in the first case label `case true: std::String file_name;` because I think the `string` has a default-ctor so it's default-initialization is equal to value-init. But he says in the second label that `file_name` is in scope but was not initialized.

Comment: C++ primer 5th is correct.  Your guesses are incorrect.  There is no "implicitly initialized" in either situation.

Comment: @Eljay: But "implicitly initialized" is in the book.

Comment: I presume what the book means by "implicitly initialized" is that the default constructor is called.

Comment: Yes but in the second case label it is said: "file_name is in scope but wasn't initialized"?!

Comment: The `switch` statement and it's `case` labels is a structured `goto`.  The `case` labels do not have their own scopes, although you can put in your own `case 0: { ... } break;` to provide their own scoped blocks.  A variable that is defined in one `case` label, but it bypassed from being *constructed* because the `switch` value goes to a subsequent `case` label will not have been *constructed*.  My own recommendation is:  *don't do that*.  (C++ gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.)

Answer (score 3):

The term "implicit initialization" sounds technical. But it's gobbledygook. It means *nothing*.

And the compiler doesn't use this made-up term *either*. To wit:

```
int main()
{
    struct Foo {
        void some_member() {}
        int a = 1;
    };
    int val = 0;
    switch (val){
        case 1:
            Foo f;
            break;
        case 2:
            f.some_member(); // use f;
    }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:12:14: error: jump to case label
   12 |         case 2:
      |              ^
<source>:10:17: note:   crosses initialization of 'main()::Foo f'
   10 |             Foo f;
      |                 ^
```

And that's all. Initialization, plain and simple. When you remove the initializer for the member `Foo::a`, there's no more initialization, and the compiler will be OK with that:

```
int main()
{
    struct Foo {
        void some_member() {}
        int a;
    };
    int val = 0;
    switch (val){
        case 1:
            Foo f; // OK - no initialization at all
            break;
        case 2:
            f.some_member(); // use f
            if (f.a) {};     // undefined behavior, a is uninitialized here
    }
}
```

Now, `f.a` is not initialized, and that's OK unless you attempt to use its value. The access to `f.a` doesn't cause a compile-time failure, but is undefined behavior, just as-if you wrote the following:

```
int main() {
   int a;
   if (a) {} // undefined behavior, a isn't initialized
}
```

Modern compilers can and will use the uninitialized variable/member access as an optimization hint. The code that uses the uninitialized value may be removed, for example.

Comment: OK really understood but in the book about the string object: `if (file_name.empty())`; // "file_name is in scope  but wan't initialized". It was default-initialized wasn't it? (it is of type std::string). So the book is wrong about that?

Comment: Since the code with `std::string` is not valid C++, talking about anything being in scope is nonsense. You can't analyze an invalid program as if it was valid. There's no scope, because scope is also a technical term defined for valid C++ that at least compiles.  You're not talking about scope in some abstract programming language, but scope in a C++ program. And you haven't got a C++ program there, not even a part of one (!). C++ Primer is full of subtle mistakes like this, and IMHO is thus a very confusing book.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa No, `file_name` is not initialized in `case false:`, only declared.

Comment: @S.M. It's not declared or anything else that would be a term of relevance in C++. The code snippet is invalid, so trying to analyze it like that is meaningless and only adds to the confusion. `file_name` is some text that has no meaning in C++ in this case. You're discussing fantasy at this point.

Comment: The error message definitely says it **crosses initialization of** file_name, not file_name 
 is **undefined** .

Answer (score 2):

According for example to the C++ 17 Standard (9.7 Declaration statement)

> 3 It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that
> bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps91 from
> a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in
> scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the
> variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default
> constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of
> these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared
> without an initializer

The class `std::string` does not has a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor.

In this code snippet

```
struct Foo{};
switch(val){
    case 1:
       Foo f; // ok not-implicitly initialized like std::string
    break;
    case 2:
        f.some_member(); // use f;
}
```

the class Foo has a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor.

and for example (15.1 Constructors)

> 6 A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> (6.1) — its class has no virtual functions (13.3) and no virtual base
> classes (13.1), and
>
> (6.2) — no non-static data member of its class has a default member
> initializer (12.2), and
>
> (6.3) — all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default
> constructors, and
>
> (6.4) — for all the non-static data members of its class that are of
> class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default
> constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is non-trivial.

Comment: What is the meaning of "jumps91"? or is it a typo?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa It's just missing formatting. Look in the standard :)

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa 91 is a reference to a footnote.:)